# Java REST Client - Bad Request (400) - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am trying to create a Java REST client to consume an api. When I try call it from my Java client, I get:

> Bad Request (400) - The request could not be understood by the server
> due to malformed syntax

**Problem**

My Rest client is not complete. I think the jwt token is being set correctly in the header, I just think that the `cr.post()` call is not correct. Perhaps the `MediaType` is wrong?

**Question**

How do I change the Rest client to call the server and get the expected response? Also how do I convert the `response` to a `ApprovalResponse` ?

Rest client (Java 7):

```
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;

private static String callSubmitApprovals(String endpointUrl, ApprovalRequest approvalRequest, String token) {
    System.out.println(endpointUrl);
    try {
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(endpointUrl);
        ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_OAUTH_BEARER);
        challengeResponse.setRawValue(token);
        cr.setChallengeResponse(challengeResponse);

        Representation response = cr.post(approvalRequest, MediaType.APPLICATION_JAVA);
        System.out.println(response);
        //ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = response;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

RESTful Api (Server) (Spring & Java 14):

```
@RestController
public class ApprovalSubmitResource {

    @PostMapping("/rest/approvals-submit")
    public ApprovalResponse submit(@RequestHeader(name="Authorization") String token, @RequestBody ApprovalRequest approvalRequest) {
        System.out.println(approvalRequest);
        ApprovalResponse approvalResponse = new ApprovalResponse();
        approvalResponse.setApprovalId("Test approvalResponse from micro service");
        return approvalResponse;
    }
}
```

POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: the `response` isn't a response, it's a `Representation` object.

Comment: @antonyh thank you for your comment. Yes, do you know why I am getting the `400` error, and how do I convert the `Representation` object to a `ApprovalResponse` object? (that's what the api returns).

Comment: Have you tried ObjectRepresentation? https://javadocs.restlet.talend.com/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/representation/ObjectRepresentation.html

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try

Comment: Also, the docs say MediaType.APPLICATION_JAVA_OBJECT

Comment: I just need to work out how to convert the `ApprovalRequest` to a `Representation serializedRepresentation`.  i.e. `cr.post(new ObjectRepresentation<Serializable>(serializedRepresentation), MediaType.APPLICATION_JAVA_OBJECT);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216632/discussion-between-antonyh-and-richard).